# SQL query - looking up from a list of values

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a, hopefully, very simple query, as there may not be a way to do this as its just plain wrong or im overthinking it.  Basically I am trying to put together an SQL query for databases that sit on Netezza.

I have an excel document with data featuring unique IDs which I can query manually using the code below, although its not practical to do manually as there are over 9000 IDs.  I firstly thought about trying to compile a similar report and just look up against eachother.  But I have not been able to reproduce the report (total noob to SQL/netezza).  Is there a way of drawing values from a range in excel to execute in an SQL query? Just wanted to check if there was a relatively simple way of doing this or not before giving up.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE UID = '2219788'
AND CURRENT_RECORD =1
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. I assume you want all the records between 1 - 9000 UIDs right? Can you elaborate and simplify your question

Comment: Sorry yes,  so the query needs to run through each of the UIDs and return the record for each `SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE UID = '2219788' WHERE UID = '2218975' WHERE UID = '2214584' etc etc etc
AND CURRENT_RECORD =1
LIMIT 100;`

Comment: So above would be the very manual way of checking the UIDs one by one.   If the data table was in a spreadsheet it would be a matter of looking up one against the other.  I need a way of drawing the IDs from a range in excel. Or I suppose I could just hardcode them manually in the query, but not sure if theres a more efficient way of doing it i.e. using sql to fetch the UIDs from the excel file.